# How to UpdateResource with knowing work progress?

Tags: delphi

Well, I'm using UpdateResource to embed a file to an executable file.
It works correctly but I want to know whether or not it is possible to show the update progress using a ProgressBar?

Comment: I'm curious, what are you doing that leads to UpdateResource taking such a long time as to need a callback? Is it just a very large file?

Comment: @David: It might be a large file. User actually selects it.

Comment: Hmm.. Progress bars lie anyway.  Given the responses indicating that it's not possible to actually know your % complete, you may just want to use a spinner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there's no callback function passed in, there's no way to receive progress information. In addition, [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't actually update the file until you call [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648032%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), so during calls to UpdateResource there's actually no progress to report anyway.

From MSDN:

> An application can use [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28VS.85%29.aspx) repeatedly to make changes to the resource data. Each call to [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28VS.85%29.aspx) contributes to an internal list of additions, deletions, and replacements but does not actually write the data to the file indicated by hUpdate. The application must use the [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648032%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function to write the accumulated changes to the file.

Comment: Minor nitpick. `UpdateResource` could well consume time. This is a transactional interface, but that doesn't necessarily mean that all the computation occurs at the commit stage of the transaction.

Comment: But isn't there any other way to do this (Something beside UpdateResource)?

Comment: the executable format is well defined. You can write your own version of UpdateResource.

Comment: @David, I guess I could give you that nitpick <g>, but minor quibble with it. I didn't say that all computation occurs at commit; I said that according to the docs the actual write doesn't occur until EndUpdateResource. :)

Answer (score 3):

No, because the [`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function does not expose any notification method to show the progress.